# Price set expire on/active on dates relative to event

Tags: price-sets

We'd like to start incorporating expire on/active on dates for some of our price sets to enable early bird pricing, as the docs indicate. Is there a way to set the expire on/active on date for a price relative to an event start date, for every event it's used for? We're on CiviCRM 4.7.27. 
Thanks,
Neal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless something recently changed, the answer is no. We've had to do a separate price set with specific dates for every one of our events. I'd much rather have one price set for each event type, as opposed to dozens of price sets each year.

Comment: thanks! looks like you're right, all i could find in the templates was logic to treat them as specific dates and not any computation.

Comment: (if you're interested: https://goo.gl/syVbXK)

Comment: I wish it would get added one of these days, as it's a common need. Early bird deadlines are commonly a number of days or weeks prior to an event. It's frustrating to have this huge list of price sets.

Comment: I've filed this: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21860